# How to have the same condition for 2 variables in the same line?

Tags: c, if-statement, variables, conditional-statements, constraints

I have this condition `if (n >= 1) && (n <= 10^4)` and I would like to know how can I have the same condition for another variable in the same line, instead of being for `n` being to `n` and `m` (for example).

I tried to add the `n` and `anotherVariable` but I couldn't figure out how to do it without giving me bugs.

Comment: You are missing `()` around your entire condition for the `if`. Also `^` in c is **not** exponentiation (it's bitwise XOR).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many as you require:

```
if ((n >= 1) && (n <= 10^4) && (condition))
```

NB that the `&&` operator short-circuits. If the first expression is `false`, the rest of the expressions shall not be evaluated and the `if` block shall not be entered.

The braces around the expressions are not necessary, but improves readability.

Also note that the `^` operator is the bitwise exclusive-or operator in C.

C does not have a built-in operator for exponentiation, but the standard library provides some functions for it.

```
#include <math.h>

double pow(double x, double y);
float powf(float x, float y);
long double powl(long double x, long double y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//include math.h library
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
if(n>=1 && n<=pow(10,4))
{
  printf("This the condition you asked for");
}
}
```

Comment: This answer shows the exact same approach as the accepted one.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.